# How to create a global variable from the output of a Tumblr theme option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, themes, tumblr

I am trying to create something like this so that when you go into Tumblr theme options and choose a colour, it will be set as a global variable and then in an external jQuery file I can use the data.

This is an example of what I've got:

Theme option:

```
<meta name="color:Colour for global variable" content="#aaaaaa">
```

Global variable:

```
<script>
globalColour = "{color:Colour for global variable}"
</script>
```

And the code in the external jQuery file:

```
backgroundColour: '"' + globalColour + '"'
```

FYI, "backgroundColour" is an external option in a js file.
I am not sure how to get this to work, help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Create an object and it will be attached to the `window` namespace:

```
   minedeep = {
     globalColour : {color:Global Color}
   };
```

In the external file you can get the value using `window.minedeep.globalColour`. Using an object will avoid polluting the namespace and helps keep things organised.

Comment: @Minedeep in what sense didn't it work? Your external file would have to be included after the code above.

Comment: No need to use `$(function () {})` in this case. Also variables defined outside functions or simply without `var` are automatically attached to `window`

Answer (score 1):

You can access Tumblr options this way too:

```
var globalColour = $('meta[name="color:Nav"]').attr('content');
```

But I'm assuming the only issue with your code is those added quotation marks.
The result of `'"' + globalColour + '"'` is `'"#aaaaaa"'`. See the duplicate marks?

This is all you need when applying it with `.css()`:

```
backgroundColour: globalColour
```